# New York University not showing up in autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Using the `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` js library I am creating an auto-completed text box to search for locations. However, it seems like some places are given lower rankings in then they should. For example, querying `new york university` will return streets with the word university in the street name. However, the query `new york university n` (note the 'n' at the end) will return the "New York University" location.

Code:

```
        var input = document.getElementById('locationSearchBox');
        var options = { };
        autocompleteTop = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteTop, 'place_changed', function () {
            place = autocompleteTop.getPlace();
        });
```

Question:
Has anyone come across this issue? And is there a way to boost new york university (or universities in general) ranking or otherwise correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you filter Autocomplete results by `establishment` type to filter out addresses. Refer to Google's [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete), and [here's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area) a code example.

You can also try it out in Google's [Autocomplete sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete). Select "Establishments" and type "new york university". You'll get as second result `New York University, New York, NY, USA`.

Hope this helps!